# Is there a way to vertically fit web page in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I need that my `UIWebView` shows me an entire web page, from the top to the bottom (it doesn't matter if the page is very long and I don't care if I'm not able to read it, I just want to see ALL the page).

So, how do I vertically fit the page in the web view?
Scales to fill, Aspect fit etc... don't work.
Thanks.

Comment: Please note this has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE`.

Comment: please add some of your code that is not working for you so that I can see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using the following line of code:

```
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

This will scale the page to adjust both horizontally and vertically within your `UIWebView`.

Answer (score -1):

You can sacle with javascript function

```
 NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;"];
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything to my webpage. I modify that value "1.5" and the result is the same.

Comment: Use at webViewDidFinishLoad method

Comment: It seems like only positive numbers work, I need a zoom-out to see all the page, not a zoom-in.

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat:` when you don't pass it any arguments, this should be throwing a warning? Why have you even got that `NSString`? Why not just do `[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;"];`?

Comment: @Popeye yes i can but thats not the issue can u show the warning. you should down vote when i put wrong answer. otherwise you have to do edit my answer.

Comment: @SunnyShah your answer is wrong and lacks any explanation so that is the reason for the downvote, as for me editing your answer I am not here to correct your mistakes. `stringWithFormat:` expects at least one argument, so where is this argument in your answer?

Comment: @Popeye if you am not here to correct any of mistakes. then you be should not here.  By the way thanks

Comment: I am more then happy correcting spelling and grammar but correcting your incorrect code isn't what anyone is here for. The answer is yours and yours alone, why would I correct your code when I can just give a correct answer myself? No one is here to correct your mistake and it is a mistake to think people will correct them for you. Leaving uncorrected as well just means that the -1 will remain, correcting your own answer will get this removed. This is how Stackoverflow works if you don't like it don't use it that simple.

Answer (score -1):

```
 [webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

or

```
 [webview sizeToFit];
```

`setScalesPageToFit:` gives output like [this](http://screencast.com/t/9GZDtm6TUe7q)

Sometimes `myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;` doesn't work so we have to set it that's why I written `[myWebView setscalesPageToFit:YES];` I have faced this type of problem in `UIButton` that `button.text = @"long text";` does not work but when I use `[button setTitle:@"long text" forControlState:UIcontrolStateNormal];` it worked. So may be it will work for you

Comment: Can you explain your answer, why use one of these over what everyone else is saying.

Comment: Don't explain your answer in the comments, explain it in your answer. And just so you know `setScalesPageToFit:YES` has already been provided as an answer and didn't work so this makes your answer wrong.

Comment: Please amend your answer with your explanation.